# Сортировка Map на Java

Tags: java, сортировка, map

Имеется `Map` и содержит такие данные

```
{markFV=[6, 1, 8, 90], mark01=[341, 144, 541, 501, 23]}
```

Как отсортировать числа по убыванию, т. е. получить такой вид:

```
{markFV=[90, 8, 6, 1], mark01=[541, 501, 341, 144, 23]
```

Если коротко, то такие данные получаются путём `jsonObject.append`, затем присваиваю переменной Map, JSON объект с помощью `Map map3 = jsonObject.toMap();` И получаю такие данные. Остаётся отсортировать внутренние массивы.

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отсортировать значения в карте можно с помощью метода [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)):

```java
Map<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("markFV", new int[]{6, 1, 8, 90});
map.put("mark01", new int[]{341, 144, 541, 501, 23});

map.forEach((key, value) -> Arrays.sort(value));

// вывод
map.forEach((key, value) ->
        System.out.println(key + "=" + Arrays.toString(value)));

// markFV=[1, 6, 8, 90]
// mark01=[23, 144, 341, 501, 541]
```

Answer (score 1):

если у тебя `Map<String, Integer>`, то очень лаконично можно отсортировать массивы вот так:

```
map.values().forEach(array -> Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder()));
```

Если же там `int`, то получается менее привлекательно (извиняюсь за "изящную" сортировку, я думаю суть вопроса не в том как вы ее реализуете у себя):

```java
for (Map.Entry<String, int[]> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    int arrLength = entry.getValue().length;
    Arrays.sort(entry.getValue());
    int[] newArr = new int[arrLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        newArr[newArr.length - (i + 1)] = entry.getValue()[i];
    }
    entry.setValue(newArr);
}
```